# Does Sprite kit (objective C) have the equivalent of CCSpawn actions: used in Cocos2d

Tags: sprite-kit

CCSpawn - combining two actions (in cocos2d)
any idea what that might be called in spritekit?

```
//Cocos2d
id wobble 
= [CCSpawn actions:scaleHBouncing,scaleVBouncing, nil];
```

//what I have at the moment I haven't tested it a whole lot
but it seems to be working

```
id spawn = 
[SKAction group:@[[SKAction repeatActionForever:xScaleAction],  
[SKAction repeatActionForever:yScaleAction]]];
[Rock runAction:spawn withKey:@"wobble"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't use Cocos2D before, but going by your description I'd say you were looking to create an [action group](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/group:); for running `SKAction`s in parallel. For example:

```
let group = SKAction.group([action1, action2])
```

You can also create [sequences of actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) for running your actions in sequentially:

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action1, action2])
```

Comment: Thanks ABakerSmith, 
It's enough of an idea to get me started so I'll mark it as right unless another answer comes along.

- I'm not using swift (I'll update my code with what I have )
hopefully it helps someone.

thanks!

Comment: You said, 'unless another answer comes along'? Is there something missing from my answer that would help answer your question more fully? :)

Comment: I've already marked it as right (although I needed to change the syntax since im not using swift - as stated in the original question) 
"Groups" was the key word and got me on the right path. - thanks again